# Split dataframe based on empty column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe, I want to split it into two dataframe if the "FT" column is empty

```
df

    HomeTeam    AwayTeam         FT
0   Colo Colo   U. De Concepcion    
1   Cobresal    U. Espanola 
2   Deportes    S. Wanderers    
3   La Serena   A. Italiano      A
4   O'Higgins   Colo Colo        D
5   Palestino   Coquimbo         D
```

Tried this code but `df` still the same

```
if "" in df['FT']:
    df1 = df[df['FT'] == '']
    df = df[df['FT'].notna("")]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the column is not missing (na) but has as value '' (empty string). In that case you can do:

```
df_missing = df.loc[df['FT'] == "", :]
df_not_missing = df.loc[df['FT'] != "", :]
```

The .loc allows you to select rows for which the values match some criteria, columns for which the values match some criteria or both. The first indexer is for selecting rows, the second (optional) for selecting columns.